# After redirecting to `www` is it problematic if my sitemap XML has non-www URLs?

Tags: redirects, canonical-url, xml-sitemap, no-www

I'm confused about canonical issue. I've setup in *.htaccess* to redirect the URLs without `www` to `www`.

Now the URLs in this link in `http://www.example.com/sitemap` are all without `www`. Is this going to affect anything?

Will `http://www.example.com` and `http://indiacustomercare.com` be considered same or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd properly set redirect 301 from *.htaccess*, robots will know your preferred URL starts with `www` and they will index it using `www` because redirect 301 indicates no-www is removed permanently.
Additionaly You can tell Googlebot `www` is your preferred URL, login into Google Webmaster Tools go to Site configuration -> settings and select Display URLs as `www.example.com`

If you are going to use absolute URLs in your internal links it will be better to be consistent with your preferred domain. If you don't want to bother about inserting `http://www.example.com/` in your links' href then don't include protocol and domain there, just set your links as `href="/folder/page.ext"`. In this way the links will be appended to your domain and bots will see them as `http://www.example.com/folder/page.ext`